# Add style/class to react-datepicker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-datepicker

So basicly how do I add a css class? I've given this a go but it ain't working:

```
<DatePicker 
       className="form-control 
       dateInput" 
       selected={startDate}  
       onChange={function(date){
                    startDate = date;
                 }
       }
/>
```

Thanks, Ed.
(It's been compiled with webpack by the way.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on where you want to add the css class, you can either use `className` prop or `popperClassName`. For more, please read the docs: https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/docs/datepicker.md